# How can i pass an array of objects from javascript to asp.net-mvc function through ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, asp.net-mvc, post

I have the following javascript code that builds up an array of objects and i am trying to push this to an asp.net-mvc action through an ajax post.  I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this below ?

javascript:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     var obj = {
        statusId: i,
        resizeable: true,
        rows: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      };
      arr.push(obj);
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   traditional: true,
   url: '/MyController/UpdateMe',
   data { info: arr },
   success: function () {  
       alert("complete");
   }
});
```

C# asp.net-mvc action:

```
public ActionResult UpdateMe(IEnumerable<UpdateInfo> info)
{
     foreach (var item in info)
     {
          Console.Write(item.statusIs + " has + " item.rows.length() + " items ");
     }
}

public class UpdateInfo
{
    public int statusId {get;set;}
    public bool resizable {get;set;}
    public List<int> rows {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around "/MyControoller/UpdateMe"? Also, "Controller" seems to be misspelled.

Comment: @linstantnoodles - sorry, that was just a typo in the question.  updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `jQuery.ajax` contentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This means that parameters sent in url string. In your case, your array transformed to string: `object&object&object....`.

To change this behavoir, you should change contentType in `jQuery.ajax` to `application/json` and convert your js object to json with `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   traditional: true,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   url: '/SchoolDetails/UpdateMe',
   data: JSON.stringify({ info: arr }),
   success: function () {  
      alert("complete");
   }
});
```

Action in debug:

[image]

Comment: Note: the "UpdateMe" action has to be marked with `[HttpPost]` also.

Comment: It does not necessarily. Attributes on the action affects for filtering request methods only, ie if added `HttpPost` attribute, then action will be accept only post requests, if action has no http attributes, it will be accept the all request methods.

Comment: @Alexander - this almost works for me.  I now see the info array being populated on the server but when i look into the array each item has the statusId populated but the rows array inside is already null (see updated question)

Comment: @leora, I think your forget to add `rows` property in `UpdateInfo` class.

Comment: @Alexander - i updated the question to reflect the latest code

Comment: And? In your action rows still null? I've updated ny answer, added screenshot, all props of `UpdateInfo` successfully initialized.

Comment: hmm . . i still see rows as null . . let me see if some other issue or typo exists

Comment: ah .  it was another typo . . all looks good now . . thank you very much for your help and patience ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a JS array as a parameter in a POST request. You have to turn it into a string to pass it to the .NET action. Consider using `jQuery.param()` to do this. It will convert the object to a string like `statusId=valueOfI&resizeable=true`. Then you change it from a string back to an array after you receive it in the action (I can't suggest a function since I don't know .NET).